# VBA to search for a cell and grab cell value to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to work in Excel that has two tabs. One downloads data from an SRSS report; because I cant seem to scrape from it directly, I'm doing a *select-all* and *paste* in to a separate sheet. I want the first sheet to populate from the extract.

The data looks like this.

[image: Extract]

What I need to do is: get the net sales so of each account, and populate it on Sheet1 which will always be at the same location, so Sheet1 will `A1` `B1` `C1` will be `account1` `account2` `account3`.

Comment: Do you have Excel for Microsoft 365? If yes, [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) might be the easiest solution here.

Comment: Yes, i do have office 365

Comment: Awesome! The tutorial I linked is probably the best way to get started with XLOOKUP. Give it a shot and edit your question if you get stuck. Also, please post the answer if you manage to make it work, so it can benefit people with the same question in the future. Your problem it's exactly unique, but it looks like there is a merged cell at the top and if the table size varies, there might be more to it than want it seems.
Lastly, if this formula-only solution works, it might be good to add the excel-formula tag to your question.